# Symbols in data frame column titles disappear

Tags: r, dataframe, symbols

When I generate this data.frame:

```
 df <- data.frame("numbers" = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
       "words / eng" = c("1 / one","2 / two","3 / three","4 / four", "5 / five"), 
       "words / spa" = c("1 / uno","2 / dos","3 / tres","4 / cuatro", "5 / cinco"))
```

Then it looks like this:

```
 > df
   numbers words...eng words...spa
 1       1     1 / one     1 / uno
 2       2     2 / two     2 / dos
 3       3   3 / three    3 / tres
 4       4    4 / four  4 / cuatro
 5       5    5 / five   5 / cinco
```

How can I have the column titles read `words / eng` and `words / spa`, instead of `words...eng` and `words...spa`, please? I am also happy with `words_/_eng` and `words_/_spa`, if that helps at all?

Comment: Add `check.names = FALSE` to `data.frame(`

Comment: Wow, so easy! Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed that post. Thank you.